# How to print Hashmap values in xhtml page

Tags: java, arraylist, xhtml, hashmap

I need your help and assistant in displaying each value in the Hashmap separately in an xhtml page. I tried to convert the hashmap to List, but I wasn't successful. My code is below:

```
private List<String> selectedTypes = new ArrayList<String>();
// The above list will store the selected types for example:(A,B)

 Map<String, String> typesNames = new HashMap<String,String>(selectedTypes.size());

        typesNames .put("A", "Type A");

        typesNames .put("B", "Type B");

        typesNames .put("C", "Type C");  

    for(String key: selectedTypes)
    {
                 System.out.println(typesNames.get(key));
    }
```

The result is showing in the console as:
Type A
Type B

So now my issue is that how to display the above output in the xhtml page in a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be work for it ;

```
<c:forEach items="#{yourBean.map}" var="entry">
   <li>Key: #{entry.key}, value: #{entry.value}</li>
</c:forEach>
```

----EDIT

```
    private Map<String, String> typesNames ;
    private List<String> selectedTypes;

    public void fillMap() {
        typesNames = new HashMap<String,String>();

            typesNames .put("A", "Type A");

            typesNames .put("B", "Type B");

            typesNames .put("C", "Type C");
        selectedTypes = new ArrayList<String>(typesNames .keySet());
    }

    public Map<String, String> getMap(){
         return typesNames ;
    }

    public List<String> getKeyList(){
         return selectedTypes;
    }
```

output ;

```
   <h:dataTable value="#{yourBean.selectedTypes}" var="key"> 
        <h:column> 
            Key: #{key}
        </h:column> 
        <h:column> 
            Value: #{yourBean.typesNames[key]}
        </h:column> 
    </h:dataTable>
```

Comment: It printed all the values